# Extract SOAP messages form svclog

Tags: .net, logging, soap, trace

### Extract SOAP messages form svclog

Hi guys!

I enabled trace listening in my app to trace soap messages.
Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

My app is a client to a web .net service.
So now I can collect infos in a svclog, well!

But how can I extract soap messages from this?
In the log soap messages were written in this form:
...
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] Data from ConnectStream#53182860::Write
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000000 : 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65-72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31 : 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000010 : 2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F-64 69 6E 67 3D 22 75 74 : .0" encoding="ut
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000020 : 66 2D 38 22 3F 3E 3C 73-6F 61 70 3A 45 6E 76 65 : f-8"?>
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000030 : 6C 6F 70 65 20 78 6D 6C-6E 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 3D : lope xmlns:soap=
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000040 : 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F-73 63 68 65 6D 61 73 2E : "http://schemas.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000050 : 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 70 2E-6F 72 67 2F 73 6F 61 70 : xmlsoap.org/soap
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000060 : 2F 65 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70-65 2F 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E : /envelope/" xmln
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000070 : 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 65 6E-63 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A : s:soapenc="http:
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000080 : 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D 61-73 2E 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 : //schemas.xmlsoa
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 00000090 : 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F 73 6F-61 70 2F 65 6E 63 6F 64 : p.org/soap/encod
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5344] 000000A0 : 69 6E 67 2F 22 20 78 6D-6C 6E 73 3A 74 6E 73 3D : ing/" xmlns:tns=

...

There's a way to extract them from svclog file?
I **cannot** modify the code, so the configuration way to trace this stuff is my preferred solution.

Thank you!
Nando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <soapExtensionTypes>
          <add 
               type="MySoapExtensionLib.MyExtension, MySoapExtensionLib"
               priority="1"
               group="High" />
        </soapExtensionTypes>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>here
```

For my needs:

1. Don't want to touch existing code
2. Cannot use WCF (using .NET 2.0)

the best way to log SoapMessages is to create a spare SoapExceptionLib class library project with a custom SoapException.
If you write your own SoapException (in this example we have MyExtension declared in MySoapExtensionLib library project), you can enable it all over your project (so for all web services calls you will do) using configuration.
If you want only some web service calls to use your extension, you should use attributes.

See this project in CodeProject to have a working example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/Soap_Extension_Progress.aspx
Hope this helps.
Bye,
Nando

Answer (score 0):

If this is a client created with "Add Service Reference", then you can configure [message tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx). This will show you the messages in XML.

Comment: Yes, it is. I enabled tracing in config, and as result I get a *.svclog file, that is a common xml.  But I cannot extract SOAP messages from this.  
Do you know a method I can use?  Thank you!

Comment: You are talking about Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)?  I used it, but it cannot extract plain soap messages, too.  :-(

Comment: I am talking about configuring message tracing. Please read the article and its sub-articles. You could then view the message traces using the tool, or could use the XML directly (the .svclog files are XML)

Comment: Yes, but I cannot extract plain SOAP messages; they are reported in chunks, have you ever tried looking at one svclog? By the way, thank you for your interest!

Comment: You're wrong. Configure **message logging**, as shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx. Configure it to log the entire message. You will want to turn off encryption while you're doing this. You will find the entire SOAP message under `MessageLogTraceRecord`.

Comment: Thak you fo patience, John! My bad, I didn't configure  <system.serviceModel> section; but configuring it where are created SOAP log files? What did you mean with *MessageLogTraceRecord*? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Searching for more info, I found what did you mean; but probably the problem is that my client is not a WCF client: I work with old plain Web Services in .NET 2.0. :-(

Comment: @Ferdinando: that's why I said, "If this is a client created with "Add Service Reference"". I said that six days ago.

Comment: Yes, I read "service" as "web"... I'm a dumb, sorry. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @Ferdinando: now that we're clear about that, why not start using "Add Service Reference" on the client? It works with ASMX or WCF services, but among many other things, you'd get that out of the box message tracing.

Comment: John, please let me say before that I don't want to make another fool figure, but...  I can work only in .NET 2.0 (just I said in my previous comment), due to Win2000 compatibility (unfortunately for me). Service References can't be added in 2.0 projects, as far as I know: or am I wrong again? :-)   Thank you John for helping me.

Comment: @Ferdinando: no, you're right. You're stuck. Sorry. Your only option would be to implement a SoapExtension. See the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx and follow it word for word until you get it to work - only then should you make any modifications. It's touchy, but it works.

Comment: John, thank you for your suggestion.I used a SoapExtension in past, and now I know is the only way to do what I need. Featuring my program to enabling or disabling logging of soap messages for all web service methods I call (40-50) would be task I cannot schedule now, but I will give it a try. Thank you! Nando

Comment: @Ferdinando: Consider simply turning all logging on or off for all methods. You don't need to put attributes on your methods in order to trigger the SoapExtension. If I remember correctly, one of the "init" overrides (the one that doesn't provide a MethodInfo) will be called, simply by configuring the extension in web.config. The extension can then be active for all web services and all operations.

Comment: John, I work on the client side. I suppose I have to work on the web service proxy-class, altering VS auto-generated code; so I must to do same work for all my proxy classes, remembering to report modifications after updating a web reference. Not a nice work, you can agree with me... :-)

Comment: @Ferdinando: in my opinion, you should _never_ alter generated code. Why did you bring that up?

Comment: Yes, my opinion is same as yours... :-)  Mine was just an hypothesis, I don't know how to do this. :-)

Comment: @Ferdinando: I don't have time now to find the exact location, but look in the SoapExtension documentation. Somewhere it documents how to configure it in web.config. Maybe in the web.config documentation.

Comment: John, I have not a web.config, I'm working on a console application, a client of web services written by 3rd party people! :-)

Comment: @Ferdinando: then it uses _applicationName_.exe.config. Same thing.

Comment: Mmm... I read something about; if you write your own SoapExtension, you can enable and use it "worldwide" in you project using configuration; I will try to explain in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I used this piece of code some moths ago, but I cannot remember where I found it.
It do the trick, after all, but is not an elegant solution.

Bye, Nando

```
        ...

    //call the web service method
    var myResponseData = ws.CallMyWebServiceMethod(myRequestData)
    //call this method just after the web servcice method call, or it will not work!
    DiagnoseResponseProblem();
    ...


    private void DiagnoseResponseProblem()
    {
        HttpContext hc = HttpContext.Current;
        string SoapResponse = null;
        string SoapRequest = null;

        // Post processing debugging pull out the actual soap message and debug it.
        if (hc != null)
        {
            SoapRequest = hc.Items["SOAPRequest"].ToString();
            SoapResponse = hc.Items["SOAPResponse"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                SoapResponse = System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.GetData("SOAPResponse").ToString();
                SoapRequest = System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.GetData("SOAPRequest").ToString();
                System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("SOAPResponse");
                System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("SOAPRequest");

                //NANDO: saving SOAP messages
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(SoapRequest);
                xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\soap-request.xml");
                xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(SoapResponse);
                xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\soap-response.xml");
            }
            // Ignore...most likely this system does not 
            // have the remote message context setup.
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```